# Problems killing child process invoked in Java

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

From within my program, I invoke a Linux process, read the output from that process, process it and then sleep until the next iteration.  The problem I'm having is that the process I call doesn't always die, even when I do a `childProcess.destroy()`. Here's the code:

```
while(true) {
   Process childProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./getData");
   InputStream input = childProcess.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader inPipe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
   while((lineRead = inPipe.readLine()) != null) {
      // do stuff
   }
childProcess.destroy();
inPipe.close();
input.close();
}
```

The vast majority of the time, ./getData runs, exits gracefully and my program works as it should.  But....sometimes it doesn't exit and just sits there consuming CPU.  I need a way of killing it off.  I also tried adding this BEFORE I invoke it but this didn't work:

```
Process killGetData = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill -9 getData");
killGetData.destroy();
```

I'm guessing that perhaps I'm getting stuck in the inner while() loop.

Any thoughts, ideas and tips gratefully received.  Many thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 1):

You must close the input pipe *to* the child process to terminate it. Add

```
childProcess.getOutputStream().close();
```

(it's an output stream for the parent process but the input for the child).

[EDIT] Also don't forget to call `childProcess.waitFor()` to clean up the zombie process.

Comment: Hi Aaron, firstly - thanks for the reply. Can you explain this in some more detail please?  I've looked at many examples of what I'm trying to do and they all pretty much say the same thing.  How would I use the getOutputStream?  Sorry for the stupid question but I'm still quite new to all this

Comment: Sorry, forgot the ".close()" :-) The problem is that the child process reads from stdin (== parent's output stream). It will terminate when the stream is closed. Also don't forget to call "waitFor()". This will clean up the process if it has become a "zombie" process.

Comment: Thanks again for your response Aaron. I will give this a go :)

Comment: That only works if the subprocess terminates when its stdin is closed; most do (well, of the things that you often want to run as subprocesses) but some don't.

Comment: @Donal: My point is: It's always *safe* to close stdin but you will *sometimes* get into trouble if you forget it.