# Process does not kill child process

Tags: java

I have a process that does ssh every 5 minutes or so. Like this

```
private String runProcess() throws IOException {
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh","-c","ssh hostname echo hello");
   Process process = pb.start();
   if(!process.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            LOGGER.info("Taking too long");
            process.destroy();
   }
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    int exitVal = process.waitFor();

    if (exitVal != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exitVal);
    }
    process.destroy();
    return output.toString();

}

/// more code to do something with output of the ssh.
```

Now, the ssh process works just fine and I get the desired output and exit value as 0.
Just out of curiosity, I ran `ps aux` on the docker container the code is running on and the list of ssh commands was massive and sitting as 'defunct'. I assume these are 'child' processes of the process command I execute in the method above. Is there a way I can kill them too in the method above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931231/problems-killing-child-process-invoked-in-java) ?
According to the issue you should try closing the reader linked to the process.

Comment: Yeah, I tried closing the input/output stream of the process. But looks like there are still zombie ssh processes left